# Ajax call in web2py with a # passed in request.vars chops the later part

Tags: ajax, web2py

```
var x = "www.something.com#something"

ajax("default?q="+x,"","");
```

Here, in the controller, the value obtained in request.vars is only www.something.com
instead of 
www.something.com#something

Looks like anything written after # is not taken into consideration.

Although it works fine when passed a "name" but not sure why this won't work in the above scenario. Please help.

Comment: `#` is client-side only (in principle). It's one of the reserved characters for URLs. See point 2 in [this blog post](https://blog.httpwatch.com/2011/03/01/6-things-you-should-know-about-fragment-urls/) and [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier).

Comment: very nice! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `#` symbol in a URL represents a [fragment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier), a fragment is not likely to be included in `request.vars` so you will need to encode the value `q` with something like [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) before sending it in a request.

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer, but then should I use encodeURIComponent() if i am preparing the request from front end ( as front end won't be able to call urllib.urlencode once a page load?